# OnClickListener not getting fired for an image button inside a ListView using Custome Adapter

Tags: android, listview, imagebutton

I have spent so much time searching for solutions and tried different ways but couldn't find where it goes wrong.

I am developing an app where I have an `ImageButton` as child element of a `listView` (I have done this using Custom Adapters). Upon executing `OnClick` of the `ImageButton`, nothing happens.

My fragment_tweets.xml looks as follows:

```
           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
           <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
       <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout                                       android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/lvTweets" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>


item_tweet.xml




 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/profile_image_view_length"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_image_view_length"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:id="@+id/ivProfilePicture"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
           android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tvUserName"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivProfilePicture"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivProfilePicture"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_10dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"/>



     <com.codepath.apps.twitterclient.helpers.LinkifiedTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tvBody"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivProfilePicture"
            android:autoLink="all"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_10dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"/>
            />

        <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_10dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_10dp"
        android:id="@+id/ivClock"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvTimeofPost"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_clock"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_10dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvTimeofPost"
        android:textColor="@color/gray"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_10dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ivPostImage"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvBody"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvBody"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvBody"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tvTimeofPost"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/tvTimeofPost"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_10dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ivPostImage"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ivPostImage"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/ivPostImage"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ivPostImage"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/ivPostImage"
        android:weightSum="3">
               <TextView   android:id="@+id/tvReply"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray"  android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/reply_small"        android:layout_below="@+id/ivPostImage"
                   android:clickable="false"
                   android:focusable="false"
                   android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvRetweetCount"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/retweet_small"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:drawablePadding=".5dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_13sp"  android:layout_below="@+id/ivPostImage"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tvReply"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvFavoriteCount"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/favorite_small"
                    android:drawablePadding=".5dp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_13sp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/ivPostImage"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tvRetweetCount"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

getView() of Adapter looks like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Tweet tweet = getItem(position);
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;

    // If it's a retweeted tweet, display the original
    if (tweet.getRetweeted() != null) {
        tweetToDisplay = tweet.getRetweetedStatus();
    } else {
        tweetToDisplay = tweet;
    }
    if(convertView==null){
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.item_tweet, null);
        convertView.setClickable(true);
        convertView.setFocusable(true);
        viewHolder.ivProfilePicture = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivProfilePicture);
    }else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
   viewHolder.ivProfilePicture.setImageResource(0); // clear out the old image
    // For Rounded image in profile picture
    Transformation transformation = new RoundedTransformationBuilder()
            .borderColor(Color.BLACK)
            .borderWidthDp(1)
            .cornerRadiusDp(30)
            .oval(false)
            .build();
    Picasso.with(getContext()).load(tweet.getUser().getProfileImageUrl())
            .transform(transformation)
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .into(viewHolder.ivProfilePicture);
    Log.v("Tweets Adapter","Before onclick of profile pic");
    viewHolder.ivProfilePicture.setTag(tweet.getUser().getScreenName());
    viewHolder.ivProfilePicture.setFocusable(false);
    viewHolder.ivProfilePicture.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    viewHolder.ivProfilePicture.setClickable(true);
    // View listener for showing the profile of user
    viewHolder.ivProfilePicture.setOnClickListener(new      View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             Log.v("Adapter ", "inside onclick method");
            // Launch the profile activity directly from the fragment
            listener.profileClicked(tweet.getUser());
        }
    });
     return convertView;
   }
```

I have already tried various solutions posted.. Any help would be great.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: And those various solutions you tried are ...?

Comment: I have tried using customlisteners, I have tried the following attribute in the root tag of the item_tweet.xml android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants". I have also made all the other elements in the list view to  android:focusable="false" and  android:focusableInTouchMode="false". I have also made the textView non selectable by default ( android:textIsSelectable="false"). As per the solutions available for the similar issues. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your else statement use this:

```
viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
convertView.setClickable(true);
convertView.setFocusable(true);
```

Your convertview is focusable and clickable when is drawing but not when is redrawing.